# What is the partial fraction of $\frac{x}{((x)^2+1)^2}$

Tags: partial-fractions

I was trying to find the partial fraction of

$$\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$
By the method of assuming

$$\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{(Ax+B)}{(x^2+1)} + \frac{(Cx+D)}{(x^2+1)^2} $$

But, my values for $A, B$ and $D$ are coming $0$.
i.e. $$A=B=D=0$$ and $$C=1$$

Which is directly equal to 
$$\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

So, technically **I got *NO* solution or Partial Fraction**

I am afraid if I'm doing any foolish mistake but, please help me out in this issue. I haven't practised Partial Fractions since a long time.

Thank you so much in advance! 
Great Day Ahead!

Comment: The ansatz that you are using only works when your rational function has a denominator that is a $\textbf{linear term}$ squared. The correct ansatz here is $\frac{x}{(x^{2} + 1)^{2}} = \frac{A}{x + i} + \frac{B}{x-i} + \frac{Cx + D}{(x+i)^{2}} + \frac{Ex + F}{(x - i)^{2}}$. I'm not sure if you wanted your partial fractions to have complex coefficients, but this will give you the complete partial fraction expansion of $\frac{x}{(x^{2} + 1)^{2}}$

Comment: This is right. You start off with a fraction in the form you require, and when you do the calculations they show that this is the right decomposition. You didn't get "no solution", just an unexpected solution.

Comment: @AdamHiggins You can decompose into partial fractions in the way suggested in the question. For example if integrating a rational function over the reals the factorisation of the denominator into linear and quadratic factors with real coefficients does make sense.

Comment: @MarkBennet I'm not sure I understand your point

Comment: @AdamHiggins You say this only works with linear factors. It can be done perfectly well with irreducible quadratic factors.

Comment: @MarkBennet I'm still not sure I understand your point. My statement was about this very specific circumstance, about the particular ansatz he was using. Could you perhaps give an example to demonstrate your point?

Comment: @AdamHiggins I agree with MarkBennet's point, Check here —  [link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/PartialFractions.aspx)

Comment: @AdamHiggins Thanks for the suggestion of trying complex number.

Comment: @AdamHiggins As you will see from my comment., I think OP is right and his method is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Well, *of course* the solution of the form $\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2+1)^2}$ is $\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}$; *that's what you started with*. If you want another partial fractions expression, use complex numbers. If the point of the exercise is to integrate the function, you'd be better off substituting $y=x^2+1$.

Comment: The cope of breaking $$\frac{x}{((x)^2+1)^2}$$ into Partial Fractions is to evaluate the value of it's Inverse Laplace Transform. Will it help, if I use complex numbers here?

Comment: @NavedTHESheikh Definitely.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $$x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)$$ where $$i^2=-1$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I am yet trying it out. Will tell you if it works. 